# Any number of whitespaces

Tags: regex

My pattern: `\s^SID\d{3,}$\s`

I want to allow any number of leading and trailing whitespaces, but it doesn't seem to work. What did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want whitespace to ALWAYS be there then:

```
^\s+SID\d{3,}\s+$
```

If you want whitespace to be OPTIONAL then:

```
^\s*SID\d{3,}\s*$
```

Note that if you put a plus after anything it means "1 or more" whereas an asterisk means "zero or more".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Forgot to mention that the spaces are optional.

Answer (score 4):

The `\s` go after the beginning of line anchor and before the end of line anchor. After that, you need the `*` quantifier.

```
^\s*SID\d{3,}\s*$
```